# Apply html canvas to a div

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Im trying to apply a canvas to an specific div

```
<div id="wrapper-2"></div>
```

I already do these in one experiment, but Im trying in a different one and the solution that I use doesn't work. Here is the link of the one that doesn't work: http://alejuu.com/demo/demo/Tearable-Cloth-master/

The solution that work in the other experiment:

```
function init() { 
    container = document.getElementById( 'wrapper-2' ); 
    canvas    = document.createElement( 'canvas' ); 
}
```

These is the link to the script that Im trying to change

http://alejuu.com/demo/demo/Tearable-Cloth-master/Cloth.js

Thanks!

Comment: You have to append the `canvas`... `document.body.appendChild(canvas)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you linked to doesn't actually use `#wrapper-2`, the canvas html is already on the page and is getting applied with:

```
canvas = document.getElementById('c');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = 560;
canvas.height = 350;
```

---

If you want to add the `<canvas>` to the div and initialize on that, you need to append the `<canvas>` to the container `<div>`, this is what you have:

```
function init() { 
    container = document.getElementById( 'wrapper-2' ); 
    canvas    = document.createElement( 'canvas' ); 
}
```

You are creating the container `<div>` and the `<canvas>` correctly (as far as I can see) but what you're missing is adding the `<canvas>` to the container `<div>`:

```
function init() { 
    container = document.getElementById( 'wrapper-2' ); 
    canvas    = document.createElement( 'canvas' ); 

    container.appendChild(canvas)
}
```